# Scholarship in Germany for summer 2022

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics, funding, germany

Is it possible to still find a scholarship for summer semester 2022 in Germany ?
I recently applied for admission in a German university for summer semester , I just need now a scholarship in order to finance the living expenses.
I could't find anyone

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Scholarships for people with unknown background are hard to find. You will have to provide more details for a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [German Academic Exchange Service](https://www.daad.de/en) has a searchable scholarship database:
https://www2.daad.de/deutschland/stipendium/datenbank/en/21148-scholarship-database/

The question mentions mathematics as field of study. Generally, if certain basic criteria required for university admission are fulfilled, it won't be particularly hard or competitive to sign up for semesters or to be admitted generally to study for an undergraduate degree in Germany at many universities (unless it's a degree in law or medicine). As the question referred to "just" needing a scholarship on top of that: these scholarships are likely very competitive to win though.

Comment: Scholarships for undergraduates are almost non-existent. Undergrads usually need to find a student job.